# using fetch on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am quite new to Javascript and have googled this problem with no joy so was hoping someone could help me with this problem.

I am using fetch to grab a file to update my database.
It all works perfectly on desktops however it does not work at all on mobile.
Using alerts in my function I know it's the fetch not working, as an alert will fire if placed before the fetch but not when placed after.

I have included the polyfill in my code and still have no luck.

Here is my fetch code.

```
     function dbPunch() {
                  console.log("function fired");

                fetch('db-punch.php', {
    method: 'GET'
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log("fetch worked");
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("fetch error");
    alert("fetch error");
});

                  }
```

I have tried it in its simplest form and no luck there.

```
function dbPunch() {
                  console.log("function fired");
                    alert("clicked");
                  fetch('db-punch.php');


                  }
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong? Thanks

Comment: which polyfill are you using? do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: I am using https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.js?features=es6,fetch and I have also tried https://github.com/github/fetch 

I am not getting any errors in the log. The only thing I am going by is the fact my alert fails to fire when placed directly after the fetch

Comment: if you can look at the server's access logs, does the request from your mobile show up in there? the only thing that makes sense for getting no response and no error is if no response at all is sent by the server.

Comment: I've logged into my control panel but cannot see any logs, sorry.